# New iTunes Connect issue with versioning and build strings

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Please move this question if this is not a programming related topic, however I've seen other iTunes Connect related questions posted here on SO.

Like many others who've found issues with the new iTunes Connect, I've found something that I don't want to hinder my app update being approved. It did upload fine and pass validation, and I also submitted it for review just fine.

The problem is Xcode shows the correct Version and Build strings, however, on iTunes Connect, it doesn't. It seems like it doesn't respect the zero after the decimal place in 1.03.

Could anyone tell me if this is an issue I need to resolve? Prior iTunes Connect's behaved fine with my other app updates with similar versioning.

I appreciate any insight. 2 pics showing the correct and incorrect:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs for [CFBundleVersion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102364).

> CFBundleVersion (String - iOS, OS X) specifies the build version number of the bundle, which identifies an iteration (released or unreleased) of the bundle. The build version number should be a string comprised of three non-negative, period-separated integers with the first integer being greater than zero. The string should only contain numeric (0-9) and period (.) characters. **Leading zeros are truncated from each integer** and will be ignored (that is, 1.02.3 is equivalent to 1.2.3). This key is not localizable.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: So should I reject the binary and resubmit? Odd that past iTC versions didn't care.

Comment: Since it seems they are simply ignored, I don't think there is a need to reject or change anything.

Comment: Rejected just in case. Review times are a little slower than usual so can't afford any delay.

Comment: I changed the version to: 1.1 instead.